# Abstract class and static in java

Tags: constructor, static, abstract

Hi everyone i check on the questions about using abstract class and static unfortunately i couldnt find using these two together 
so here is my question;

(im little new here and i couldn't find how to instert code )

```
package gerekenler;

public abstract class Employee {


  private int EmpId;

  private String Name;

  private int Age;

  public Employee (int EmpId, String name, int age) {

  }
}
```

and i want to insert static variables like workingdays (7) and bonus questions is it right to use private in abstract

Comment: show us your code for working days.  Also, those are not constructors..

Comment: sorryy i deleted constructor thingy
im trying to learn how to use static     
      private static int DailyWorkhours = 8;
      private static int WorkingDays =5;

Comment: I believe you also want these fields to be `final`. You should make any of your fields as hidden as possible. If subclasses of Employee won't need to know how many working days there are then make it `private` and use it only to define shared behaviour in abstract class. If subclasses need to know it, make it protected, etc. Btw. make sure you don't start your fields and methods with capital letters.

Comment: thanks for the improving comments i will keep in that mind:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you it is totally ok to define private variable in your abstract class and it is only the matter of being really public, protected or private which you should decide it yourself as a programmer.

Also if you want to create a static variable in your class do it like :

```
private static int workingDays = 5;
```

or like

```
private static int workingDays;
static {
   workingDays = 5;
}
```

but in your case I suggest to create an enum like

```
public enum WorkingDays {
    Monday,
    Sunday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday
    Friday;
}
```

and use it in your class(even you can declare (private) it inside your class)

Comment: You're welcome. But remember that you could find all these stuff by searching in SO posts and I just kinda wrap it up